# Modern alternative to Tranglos KeyNote

Tags: windows, android, note-taking, synchronization

Been using it pretty happily for like 15 years, but now the need for cross-device access and synchronization has finally become apparent. What I'm looking for is:

1. All or most of Tranglos KeyNote functionality, including tree structure, rich text formatting, text search. Explicit tagging would be nice too.
2. Synchronization between Windows 7 SP1 and Android.
3. Data should be stored locally on my devices **and** recoverable without access to my note-taking software account. Why? Because I had my Microsoft account temporarily blocked twice already without any reason, warning or explanation. Google is known to do that too, only per-document rather than per-account. I'm not going to trust my vital data to any buggy third party security scripts anymore, thanks.

I'm looking at Evernote right now. Seems to be close to what I need, but the option to recover data without access to my account is not clearly described. Any better ideas?

Please note that while I'm all about opensource, in this particular case opensource alternatives are welcome only if they've been around for long enough, in production stage and with no major issues. The data in question is just too important to me to use it for beta testing.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you take a look at **RightNote** (http://www.bauerapps.com/rightnote). It was very much inspired by the original KeyNote and by the ideas that were planned for it's v2, so it has all of those features and more.

With regard to your question:

- It includes support for importing KeyNote files (.knt)
- The main focus of the application is to be a powerful desktop information manager. However, mobile access is also an important goal of ours.
- Currently, we provide an **Export to WebBook** option which allows you to view your notes via any browser, so
- For Android, you can copy all the exported files to your device, or an even better option is to export your notes to Dropbox, and then use **DropSync** on your Android to download all the RightNote files automatically. You can then point your browser to the start page which will be something like `YourDropboxFolder\mobile.html`.

In the future we will be considering other options for mobile access (e.g a mobile app), however, at this point in time, the Export to Webbook does go a long way in giving you read only access to your notes.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of RightNote).